# Attended to vs attended upon

Tags: prepositions

Which is/are correct. Are they mean the same?

> The senior doctor *attended to* the patient very quietly.
>
> The senior doctor *attended upon* the patient very quietly.

Comment: "Attended upon" would be very uncommon. It's older English. "Attended to" would be the more accepted phrasing today.

Comment: could you mean "was attendant upon"

Comment: No. See it here  ,  Q4 https://www.campusgate.co.in/2014/03/error-detection-prepositions-i.html

Answer (score 1):

Attend **to** is correct. Attend upon has a different (and rather old fashioned) meaning.  We can say "the servant attended upon his master".  It would not be used in the doctor-patient relationship.  The grammar book you are using contains an error.